# Rescaling a function within an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Am I doing this correctly please?

If we have:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + y = \frac{1}{a + \epsilon y} $$

where y is a function of x.

If i need to rescale such that $ y(x) = \alpha z(x) $, is the following the correct procedure?

We substitute in for $ y(x)$ to give:

$$ \begin{align} \alpha \frac{d^2z}{dx^2} + \alpha z = \frac{1}{a + \epsilon \alpha z} \\ 
\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} + z = \frac{1}{a \alpha + \epsilon \alpha^2 z} \\
\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} + z = \frac{1}{1 + \delta z}
\end{align}
$$

Where $ \alpha = \frac{1}{a} $, $ \delta = \epsilon \alpha^2 = \frac{\epsilon}{a^2} $

Just looking for a Yes or No please, and if No a pointer as to what I may be doing wrong.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you know that $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, a > 0 in this instance.  Thankyou for the clarification.